Is there any English translation of Vachaspati's Tatparya and Udayana's Parishuddhi?
I am undertaking research on liberation in Classical Nyaya and Sankhya philosophies, and am looking for English translations of their key texts. I've found Dr. Jha's translation of the Nyaya Sutra, Vatsyayana's Bhashya and Uddyotakara's Varttika. But I haven't been able to find English translations of Vachaspatimishra's Tatparya and Udayana's Parishuddhi. Please share details regarding this if you know. Thanks.
